# Allow_url_fopen=on file_get_contents is not working on both Localhost and Server?

Tags: php, json

When trying use option `Allow_url_fopen=on file_get_contents` I got following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

How to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: Post full code and don't assume other people know what's in your IDE.